# how to save aspx file as html file and folder to local machine or server

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, filestream

in my web application my client wants to save the current aspx page as html file and also save the related file(jquery, images ...) in a folder.
basically that what is being done in the background when you right click and press "save to" in the browser and I want to do that by a click of a button(webcontrol).

i found a piece of code that will save the html file itself but i don't know how to save also the related folder.

```
private void SavePageASHtml(string location)
    {
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

        HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);

        Page.RenderControl(htmlWriter);

        htmlWriter.Flush();

        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(location, FileMode.Create);

        string siteString = stringWriter.ToString();

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(siteString);

        fileStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

        fileStream.Close();

        Response.End();

        Response.Redirect("~/PriceList.aspx");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply right click on page and save html, it will save everything direcctly linked to the page,.i.e, images,js and css

Comment: thank you
i know that but i want to make the process with the click of a button to a specific folder and a specific file.
isn't there any web control or something else that can mimic this action?

Comment: Good question, but i dont think so. Let me find out

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty old article, but it shows how to save as an MHT file, which is quite close to what I believe you want:

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20040527.asp