# How can I save HTML of rendered View?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

Basically User enters page, generates report and decides whether it should be saved or not.

If yes, then I have to save this html as static html file.

It'd be really nice if that was something like:

```
public IActionResult GetReport()
{
    (...)
    string html = View(model).ToString();
    save_to_database(html);
    return View(model);
}
```

But, the only solution that I managed to find is putting button on that page
which executes JavaScript like this one:

```
var html = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document); 

sendHTMLViaAPI(html);
```

and sending that html to API via post.

So, I'm curious whether there are C#-ish ways to do it? in Controller's method.

Also: Is that potentially dangerous? E.g. session things can be saved in that html file or user can send content of non-HTML file via API...

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558204/how-to-save-aspx-file-as-html-file-and-folder-to-local-machine-or-server

Comment: Well, nothing have changed over 8 years? :)

Comment: Sorry, is this your goal: *Converting HTML code in the razor page to string*?

Comment: @TânNguyễn Convert ``View(model)`` to string (which is HTML). Basically the page that is rendered for user, I'd also want to save e.g in string. ``string html = View(model).ToString()`` something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Return View as String in .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40912375/return-view-as-string-in-net-core)

Copy of response from that url^

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CC.Web.Helpers
{
    public static class ControllerExtensions
    {
        public static async Task<string> RenderViewAsync<TModel>(this Controller controller, string viewName, TModel model, bool partial = false)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
            {
                viewName = controller.ControllerContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
            }

            controller.ViewData.Model = model;

            using (var writer = new StringWriter())
            {
                IViewEngine viewEngine = controller.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(ICompositeViewEngine)) as ICompositeViewEngine;
                ViewEngineResult viewResult = viewEngine.FindView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName, !partial);

                if (viewResult.Success == false)
                {
                    return $"A view with the name {viewName} could not be found";
                }

                ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(
                    controller.ControllerContext,
                    viewResult.View,
                    controller.ViewData,
                    controller.TempData,
                    writer,
                    new HtmlHelperOptions()
                );

                await viewResult.View.RenderAsync(viewContext);

                return writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then just implement with:

```
viewHtml = await this.RenderViewAsync("Report", model);
```

Or this for a PartialView:

```
partialViewHtml = await this.RenderViewAsync("Report", model, true);
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you meant correctly, this solution may be what you're looking for:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult GetHTML()
{
    var model = new ModelClass() { Content = "Hi!" };

    // or
    // return PartialView("GetHTML", model);
    return PartialView(nameof(GetHTML), model);
}
```

In the file `GetHTML.cshtml`:

```
@model ModelClass 
<div>
    Content: @Model.Content
</div>
```

In the clientside, when user wants to get the HTML as string, you can try to use jquery to get it:

```
$.post('/home/gethtml').done(function (html) {
    // html is a string here..

    // <div>
    //     Content: Hi!
    // </div>

    $('body').append(html);
});
```

---

Or creating your custom service:

*ViewRender.cs*

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;
using System;
using System.IO;

public class ViewRender : IViewRender
{
    private IRazorViewEngine _viewEngine;

    private ITempDataProvider _tempDataProvider;

    private IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public ViewRender(
        IRazorViewEngine viewEngine, 
        ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider, 
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _viewEngine = viewEngine;
        _tempDataProvider = tempDataProvider;
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public string Render(string name)
    {
        var actionContext = GetActionContext();

        var viewEngineResult = _viewEngine.FindView(actionContext, name, false);

        if (!viewEngineResult.Success)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Couldn't find view '{0}'", name));
        }

        var view = viewEngineResult.View;

        using (var output = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(
                actionContext, 
                view, 
                new ViewDataDictionary<string>(
                    metadataProvider: new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), 
                    modelState: new ModelStateDictionary())
                {
                    Model = null
                }, 
                new TempDataDictionary(actionContext.HttpContext, _tempDataProvider), 
                output, 
                new HtmlHelperOptions());

            view.RenderAsync(viewContext).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            return output.ToString();
        }
    }

    public string Render<TModel>(string name, TModel model)
    {
        var actionContext = GetActionContext();

        var viewEngineResult = _viewEngine.FindView(actionContext, name, false);

        if (!viewEngineResult.Success)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Couldn't find view '{0}'", name));
        }

        var view = viewEngineResult.View;

        using (var output = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(
                actionContext, 
                view, 
                new ViewDataDictionary<TModel>(
                    metadataProvider: new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), 
                    modelState: new ModelStateDictionary())
                {
                    Model = model
                }, 
                new TempDataDictionary(actionContext.HttpContext, _tempDataProvider), 
                output,                     
                new HtmlHelperOptions());

            view.RenderAsync(viewContext).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            return output.ToString();
        }
    }

    private ActionContext GetActionContext()
    {
        var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();

        httpContext.RequestServices = _serviceProvider;

        return new ActionContext(httpContext, new RouteData(), new ActionDescriptor());
    }
}
```

*IViewRender.cs*:

```
public interface IViewRender
{
    string Render(string name);

    string Render<TModel>(string name, TModel model);
}
```

*Startup.cs*:

```
services.AddTransient<IViewRender, ViewRender>();
```

---

Usage:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IViewRender _viewRender { get; set; }

    public HomeController(IViewRender viewRender)
    {
        _viewRender = viewRender;
    }

    public IActionResult GetHTML()
    {
        string htmlWithoutModel = _viewRender.Render("Home/GetHTML");

        var model = new ModelClass() { Content = "Hi!" };

        string htmlWithModel = _viewRender.Render<ModelClass>("Home/GetHTML", model);

        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yea, that's one of solutions, but is there an C# way to do it? e.g save it while being in controller's method

Comment: @Joelty I've updated with a service to get the HTML string in the controller.

Comment: Weird, ``htmlWithModel `` throws  ``ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

System.Collections.Generic.List<T>.get_Item(int index)``